# laravel @if in datatables column

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

i have delete column that has delete button, i tried use @if ... @endif but the value is returning false

```
@if(' + data.name +' == "Admin")<a class="ml-1 btnid delete-button btn btn-outline-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal-small2">Delete </a> @endif
```

the data.name output is Admin but why the button didnt show ? any mistake for the format ?

this is the full script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        ajax: {
          url:"{{ route('DTuser') }}",
          dataSrc:""
        },
        columns : [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "email" },
            { "data": "noktp" },
            { "data": "nohp" },
            {
                "data": null,
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<a href="/profile/'+ data.id +'"><button class="delete-button btn btn-outline-warning">Edit</button></a> @if('data.name' == "Admin")<a class="ml-1 btnid delete-button btn btn-outline-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal-small2">Delete '+ data.name +'</a> @endif <a class="ml-1 btnid delete-button btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="myFunction(this)" data-id="'+ data.id +'" data-name="'+ data.name +'" href="javascript:void(0)" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal-small">Delete '+data.name+'</a>';
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: for more information, i tried @if(1 == 1), the button shown the modal, that return true, but when i tried that '+ data.name +' == "Admin" , it returning false

Comment: PHP/Blade is run on the server, Javascript on the client - you can't mix them like that

Comment: `' + data.name +'` is a _string_ and it will _never_ be the string `"Admin"`

Comment: As per what @brombeer said, the string that you are comparing does not match. I am thinking that `data.name` is a value from a parameter, maybe an object or something. Clarify that issue first.

Comment: Blade runs serverside so you can't use blade markup to compare javascript variables. I don't see a reason why you are using blade for that `if` just use plain javascript

Comment: thanks for the comment, i found another way to do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: i already got my solution from Mr. apokryfos statement, its work already, i separated my button with variable, and use plain if statement in js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i make this for good practice code

```
{
                    "data": null,
                    "render": function(data, type, row) {
                        var editButton = '<a href="/profile/' + data.id + '"><button class="delete-button btn btn-outline-warning">Edit</button></a>';
                        var deleteButton = '<a class="ml-1 btnid delete-button btn btn-outline-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal-small2">Delete</a>';
                        
                        if (data.name != "Admin") {
                            return editButton + deleteButton;
                        } else {
                            return editButton;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Blade's @if like that :

@if($data['name'] === 'Admin')
Delete {{ $data['name'] }}
@endif

Comment: I will be helpful if you could add more code to the inside of the if statement.
Like minimal code for a button or something